# Regex Visual Studio Find Replace Mystery

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Okay, this one has stumped me, but I think it's still possible.

Basically, the following line shows up in a ton of class files:

```
public class TypeBabySexByULS : SimpleObjectBase, ICCPSystemType {
```

except `TypeBabySexByULS` will be one of 215 different things, other examples like `TypeCard` or `TypeAntepartumARC`.

What I would like to do is be able to use capture groups and make it change into:

```
Baby Sex By ULS Type
Antepartum ARC Type
Card Type
```

Any stabs? Your wisdom is wholly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using? The regex engine has changed significantly with VS2012.

Comment: there's no  single **common** pattern for all  those 216 class names right!

Comment: I assume you don't want spaces in the actual output.  So essentially you need a regex that changes 
 'public class Type<Something> : SimpleObjectBase ...' to
 'public class <Something>Type : public SimpleObjectBase...'

Comment: I do want spaces, because I'm converting the names to be display names and they will almost all for the most part just be converted by hand like shown above. Here is the attribute tag for edification: [DisplayName("RenamedProperty")]